# NSUserDefaults for self created classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a problem in a usually very simple quest, I want to create a custom class containing an integer, a NSString and a NSDate. However, in my example I only use a NSString to show my problem when storing objects.

This is my class header:
    #import

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString * myString;
}
@property (retain) NSString * myString;
@end
```

and my body:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myString;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myString = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myString"];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myString = @"Hi";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject: myString forKey:@"myString"];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    myString = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

My ViewController contains two buttons called Create and Read, as well as a UILabel called label.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UserDefaultsTestViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
- (IBAction)pushCreate;
- (IBAction)pushLoad;
@end
```

I will only show the functions I've edited here:

```
#import "UserDefaultsTestViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"
- (IBAction)pushCreate {
    MyClass * myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myClass];
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"Test"];
    [myClass release];
}

- (IBAction)pushLoad {
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData * atchive = [defaults objectForKey:@"Test"];
    MyClass * myClass = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:atchive];
    label.text = myClass.myString;
}
```

However, if I run my code, I get either a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error or it displays it correctly the first time and crashes when doing it a second time, again with the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
self.myString = @"Hi";
```

Or:

```
myString = @"Hi";
[myString retain];
```

Likewise, your dealloc should have:

```
self.myString = nil;
```

or

```
[myString release];
```

Comment: I need a release althrough I never allocated any memory to my string? I thought NSStrings which have not explictly been allocated are autoreleased

Comment: @David, you need a -retain precisely because you didn't alloc the object but you're holding onto a reference to it. And after you retain the object, you'll need to release it when you're done with it. You're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS because you've got a bad pointer -- i.e. a pointer to an object that's being deallocated right under your nose.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference between myString = @"Hi" and self.myString = @"Hi". Thanks a lot